# Cannot commit an insert query in ms access via visual basic 6

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I wrote this vb6 code to commit a insert sql query in ms access db:

```
Private Sub InsertData()
    Dim sql As String
    Set MyData = OpenDatabase(App.Path + "\Archive.mdb")
    sql = "INSERT INTO Presenze(Enterprise, Employss, mYear, mMonth, mDay, WorkHours) SELECT T.[Enterprise], P.UserCode, T.[Yr], T.[Mnth], T.[Dy], T.[WorkHRS] FROM TableData T INNER JOIN Personal P On P.PID= T.[PID]"
    Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
        Mydata.Execute sql
    Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
    Call MsgBox(Mydata.RecordsAffected)
End Sub
```

I want to insert some data to the table but nothing was written in the database.
The MsgBox show 0 affected rows. But When I run the query manually on MS Access Software, it works prefect, with 2 affected rows.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you verify your connection string is working? If your SQL is working, that should tell you that either you aren't connecting to the database or the way you're sending your SQL to the database is incorrect. (Or your method of displaying the rows affects is incorrect)

Comment: The connection is working. I used this method to create a new table and it works. When I tried the make an insert nothing was affected.

Comment: It is jarring to the eye to see + used for concatentation and it can lead to subtle errors too.  Works great... until it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Execute Method (ADO Connection)", see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , for a example:

```
Private Sub InsertData()
    Dim sql As String, num As Long, Con As New adodb.Connection

    sql = "INSERT INTO Presenze(Enterprise, Employss, mYear, mMonth, mDay, WorkHours) SELECT T.[Enterprise], P.UserCode, T.[Yr], T.[Mnth], T.[Dy], T.[WorkHRS] FROM TableData T INNER JOIN Personal P On P.PID= T.[PID]"
        Con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" & App.Path + "\Archive.mdb" & ";PWD="  
    Con.Execute (sql, num, adExecuteNoRecords)

    If Con.State = 1 Then
        Con.Close
        Set Con = Nothing
    End If

    MsgBox num & " records were affected"
End Sub
```

Comment: But why the odd check to see if the Connection is open just after you opened and used it?  BTW magic numbers are bad, m'kay?  What you want there is `adStateOpen`.